# Disable table alias on Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

When I use Linq to SQL, the generated SQL uses a lot of alias, which is hard to read and diagnose.

```sql
SELECT [t4].[ServerID], [t4].[Name], [t4].[URL], [t4].[IsProduction]
FROM [dbo].[OperatorTeams] AS [t0]    
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TeamsOrganizationsACL] AS [t1] ON [t0].[TeamID] = [t1].[TeamId]    
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Servers] AS [t4] ON [t4].[ServerID] = [t2].[ServerID]
WHERE ([t3].[ServerLevelAccess] <> @p0) AND ([t3].[IsActive] = @p1) AND ([t0].[OperatorID] = @p2)
```

Is there a way to disable using table alias?